# ACCIDENTALLY ENTERED EMACS TUTORIAL HOW DO I GET BACK TO MY FILE

Tags: emacs

I was just working along when I accidentally entered the emacs tutorial and I have no idea how to get back to my file.

please help

Comment: C-x C-b. That is all.

Comment: Thank you so goddamn much.  Im new to this stuff and its not very user friendly.

Comment: There's no need to yell (in your title) or use offensive language (in your comment).

Comment: @phils answer is good. But I think that the top of the tutorial should tell users how to quit the tutorial and get back to their original buffer. I just filed a [bug report](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20371) for this. I don't see why this question should be closed as being unclear. To me it is clear: the OP fell into the tutorial and panicked, worried about how to get back to where s?he was.

Answer (score 6):

You *continue the tutorial* until you've learned how to switch buffers.

Seriously. *It's the tutorial. It exists for the purpose of answering questions like this.*

It's not tiny, but doing the tutorial isn't a *large* time investment in getting to grips with Emacs, and it will pay dividends right away by teaching you how to do lots of things (as opposed to asking this question, which has taught you only one of those things).